# custom event handler which will change Form.Label.Text

Tags: multithreading, winforms, powershell, events, event-loop

I'm able to create simple form which displays some text and do some action after button press. Here is my code I'm playing with:

```
Function Button_Click()
{
    [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Hello World." , "My Dialog Box")
    # Parent.Controls["Label1"].Text = "goodbye, world."
}

Function Generate-Form {
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms    
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

    # Build font object
    $Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Times New Roman",18,[System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Italic)


    # Build Button object
    $Button = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
        $Button.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(35,35)
        $Button.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(120,23)
        $Button.Text = "Show Dialog Box"

        #Add Button event 
        $Button.Add_Click({Button_Click})
        # $Button.Add_Click($Button_Click)

    # # Build Label object
    $Label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
        $Label.Text = "Firefox status"
        $Label.Name = "ffStatus"
        $Label.AutoSize = $True


    # Build Form object
    $Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
        $Form.Text = "My Form"
        $Form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200,200)
        $Form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
        $Form.Topmost = $True
        # $Form.Font = $Font

        # Add button to form
        $Form.Controls.Add($Button)

        # Add label to form
        $Form.Controls.Add($Label)

        #Show the Form 
        $form.ShowDialog()| Out-Null 
}
```

But now I need something more complicated. Let's say I would like to display info on the `Form.Label` about the status of firefox. I can check whether firefox is running or not

```
function Get-FirefoxStatus {
    $ffRunning = 0
    Get-Process| ForEach-Object { if ($_.Name -eq "firefox"){
        $ffRunning = 1}
    }
    Return $ffRunning
}
```

but how to show the results of `Get-FirefoxStatus` function inside `Form.Label` do I need separate thread that will periodically call  `Get-FirefoxStatus` function? Or is there some type of handler which I can register? Or some event loop? Do I need some kind of refresh button? or what to do, is this even possible in powershell?

Comment: You could add a timer to the form and in the Tick event update the label text at a specified interval.

Comment: @Theo can you please post minimum working example? Thank you

Comment: I'm on mobile now, will do when I'm back at my computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As promised, here the code you could use to change the label text in the form using a [Timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.timer).

Note that I changed the function to get the running status of Firefox to `Test-Firefox` so now it returns either `$true` or `$false`.

I left the `Button_Click` function unchanged.

```
function Button_Click() {
    [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Hello World." , "My Dialog Box")
}

function Test-Firefox {
    [bool](Get-Process -Name 'firefox' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
}

function Generate-Form {
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms    
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

    # create a timer object and set the interval in milliseconds
    $timer = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Timer
    $timer.Interval = 1000
    # create the Tick event where the text in the label is changed
    $timer.Add_Tick({
        $Label.Text = if (Test-Firefox) { "Firefox is running" } else { "Firefox is not running" }
    })

    # Build font object
    $Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Times New Roman",18,[System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Italic)

    # Build Button object
    $Button = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
        $Button.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(35,35)
        $Button.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(120,23)
        $Button.Text = "Show Dialog Box"

        #Add Button event 
        $Button.Add_Click({Button_Click})

    # # Build Label object
    $Label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
        $Label.Text = if (Test-Firefox) { "Firefox is running" } else { "Firefox is not running" }
        $Label.Name = "ffStatus"
        $Label.AutoSize = $True


    # Build Form object
    $Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
        $Form.Text = "My Form"
        $Form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200,200)
        $Form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
        $Form.Topmost = $True
        # $Form.Font = $Font

    # Add button to form
    $Form.Controls.Add($Button)

    # Add label to form
    $Form.Controls.Add($Label)

    # Stop and dispose of the timer when the form closes
    $Form.Add_Closing({ $timer.Dispose() })  # Dispose() also stops the timer.

    # Start the timer and Show the Form
    $timer.Start()
    $Form.ShowDialog()| Out-Null

    # don't forget to dispose of the form when done !
    $Form.Dispose()
}

# show the form
Generate-Form
```

Comment: Just for curiosity. Are you aware of other techniques, which leads to desired result?

Comment: @WakanTanka Well.. You can use all kinds of  events in [Windows form controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/events-in-windows-forms-controls) that when triggered do something, for instance change text in a label. Click a button, move the form, press a key, whatever. It's up to you and what you want to achieve.